# Model structures on category of diagrams : stability under composition?

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

I'm reading Dwyer-Spalinski's *Homotopy theories and model categories*, and when they define homotopy pushouts there is one point in the definition of model category that isn't checked, and doesn't seem so obvious.

Let $D$ be the category $a\leftarrow b \to c$, and $C$ a model category, they define :

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism in $C^D$, then let $\partial_a(f)$ be the pushout of

$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
X(b) @>>> X(a)\\ @V{f_b}VV @VVV\\
Y(b) @>>> \partial_a(f)
\end{CD}$

Then we obviously get a map $\partial_a(f) \to Y(a)$, which we call $i_a(f)$. We define $\partial_c(f)$ and $i_c(f)$ similarly; and let $\partial_b(f) = Y(b), i_b(f) = f_b$.

Then define on $C^D$ a weak equivalence to be a pointwise weak equivalence, a fibration to be a pointwise fibration, and a cofibration to be an $f$ such that $i_a(f),i_b(f)$ and $i_c(f)$ are cofibrations in $C$.

Then they check the axioms for a model category, but never check that all these classes of maps are closed under composition ! Now obviously weak equivalences and fibrations are, because they're pointwise, but for cofibrations it's not that easy

So my question is :

> Why are cofibrations on $C^D$ closed under composition ?

I thought it would be obvious as they didn't check it, and so tried to write the appropriate diagram, but it didn't work. We get something like :

$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
X(b) @>>> X(a)\\ @V{f_b}VV @VVV\\
Y(b) @>>> \partial_a(f) \\ @V{id}VV @V{i_a(f)}VV \\
Y(b) @>>> Y(a)\\ @V{g_b}VV @VVV \\
Z(b) @>>> \partial_a(g) 
\end{CD}$

where $f:X\to Y, g:Y\to Z$. All vertical maps displayed are cofibrations by hypothesis, and by stability under pushout of cofibrations, and we have very little information about the horizontal ones.

Then clearly we get a map $\partial_a(g\circ f)\to \partial_a(g)$, and if we prove it's a cofibration then we are done, because clearly $i_a(g\circ f)$ is the composite of this map and $i_a(g)$, but I can't really see why this map should be a cofibration.

The map $X(a)\to \partial_a(g\circ f)$ is one, and so if cofibrations had the 2-out-of-3 property, we could get that the map $\partial_a(g\circ f)\to \partial_a(g)$ does too because there's a factorization, but of course they don't in general.

Comment: Can you get it as a retract of known cofibrations?

Comment: @Randall : I also tried to see that, but I can't seem to get interesting maps both in an out of $\partial_a(g\circ f)$ to/from a fixed thing.

Comment: This is going to bother me.  I'm certain that it's obvious.

Comment: This isn't just composition of two pushouts is a pushout?

Comment: @Randall : no, there's a map inbetween and so it's not just a composition of pushouts. It probably is obvious, as Dwyer-Spalinski didn't even think of spelling it out

Comment: I give up.  I can't get it.  Let me know if you do.

Comment: Hint: Check the lifting property for $i_a(g\circ f)$ against trivial fibrations! Better yet, characterize Dwyer and Spalinski's cofibrations as the maps with left lifting against pointwise trivial fibrations. Start in the arrow category rather than the category of spans, the arguments are almost the same. Then read a more modern reference that constructs the model structure on diagrams indexed by any Reedy category. I think the moral here is that this property wouldn't hold for a class merely closed under composition and pushout-it has to be a left orthogonality class.

Comment: @KevinCarlson thank you, I'll try to see how that works out !

Comment: @KevinCarlson the argument is exactly the same for the arrow category indeed (one side doesn't care about the other in the spans), and checking that the DS-cofibrations are precisely the maps with the LLP works perfectly well (probably betterthan checking that $i_a(g\circ f)$ has the LLP, which seems like it involves a whole lot of diagrams that I don't care to write) - thank you very much ! Unless you or someone else wants to, I'll write a detailed answer when I have the time (you are welcome to do so if you have the time).

Comment: @Randall : you should check out Kevin's hint, it works really well.

Comment: @Max I thought of that, I just didn’t feel like checking it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any class $R$ of maps in a category $\mathcal C$, define
$$ \operatorname{LLP}(R) = \{ f \text{ map in } \mathcal C \mid \forall r\in R, f \text{ has the left lifting property relatively to } r\} $$

> **Lemma.** $\operatorname{LLP}(R)$ is closed under composition.

The proof is just a matter of lifting in two stages.

---

Now in your case, by definition, the trivial fibrations are the pointwise trivial fibrations. Because "they check the [other] axioms for a model category", they must prove at some point that the cofibrations lift on the left relatively to the trivial fibrations. In other words, they prove $C \subseteq \operatorname{LLP}(F\cap W)$ (where $C,F,W$ denote respectively the class of cofibrations, fibrations and weak equivalences). So you are done if you prove the reversed inclusion. Let me use the notation $(h_a,h_b,h_c)$ for maps between diagrams. Then for a map $f\in \operatorname{LLP}(F\cap W)$,

- you can see that $f_b$ is a cofibration by testing $f$ against trivial fibrations $(\mathrm{id}_1,p,\mathrm{id}_1)$ between spans of the form $1 \leftarrow X \to 1$,
- you can see that $i_c(f)$ is a cofibration by testing $f$ against trivial fibrations $(\mathrm{id}_X,\mathrm{id}_X, p)$ from  $1\leftarrow X = X $ to $1\leftarrow X \overset p \to Y$ where $p$ is a trivial fibration of $\mathcal C$,
- the cofibrancy of $i_a(f)$ is similar.

Comment: Thank you, I was going to write that later today but you saved me the trouble !